# Android NDK - socket closing when using localhost

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, android-ndk

I'm having issues with using some sockets in C++ code with Android NDK. Two sockets are created, and one reads from the other. This works *with* a network connection on Android, both *with* and *without* a network connection on another machine, but **NOT** on Android without a network connection.

Here is a *netstat* output before the socket closes. The line of interest is

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32993        127.0.0.1:46810        ESTABLISHED

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32993          0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45549          0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46811        127.0.0.1:32993        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32993        127.0.0.1:46811        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46810        127.0.0.1:32993        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32993        127.0.0.1:46810        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:5555         10.0.2.2:34217         ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 10.0.2.15:49667        10.0.2.3:53           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60262          0.0.0.0:*
```

I then attempt to read 10 bytes from the socket 127.0.0.1:46810 (header_length - filled = 10):

```
bytes = read(fd, header, header_length - filled);
```

However, 0 bytes are read. TCP_NODELAY has been set on the socket. This is the *netstat* output after the read.

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address          Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32993          0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46811        127.0.0.1:32993        FIN_WAIT2
tcp        0      1 127.0.0.1:32993        127.0.0.1:46811        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46810        127.0.0.1:32993        FIN_WAIT2
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32993        127.0.0.1:46810        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:5555         10.0.2.2:34217         ESTABLISHED
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60262          0.0.0.0:*
```

There are no problems when there is a network connection, and the addresses used are still 127.0.0.1. Why would it fail to read any bytes on localhost when there is no network connection?

Comment: I suspect it could be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679833/android-localhost-sockets-fail-when-no-data-connection

Comment: Reading zero bytes from TCP socket means the other side has closed the connection. Post your code, it's impossible for us to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was being caused by another issue. Some time after resolving the IP address into a char array, delete[] was being called on the array. When there was no network connection, the pointer was being reassigned directly to 127.0.0.1, so the program was crashing on the delete[]. Copying the IP into the array using

```
strcpy(ip, "127.0.0.1");
```

means that the pointer still points at the array, and the program does not crash when calling delete[].

Comment: Always have a "logcat" window open when doing android-ndk development.  Native crashes result in fairly dramatic log output.

Comment: @fadden: +1 for "dramatic" as a description of log output. :-)